# How to create ObjectAnimator with valueType - pathType programmatically?

Tags: android, objectanimator, android-vectordrawable

I would like to create a ObjectAnimator programmatically that represents this xml -

```
 <objectAnimator
        android:duration="@integer/eye_anim_duration"
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/anticipate_overshoot"
        android:propertyName="pathData"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:valueFrom="@string/big"
        android:valueTo="@string/small"
        android:valueType="pathType"
        />
```

In similar fashion as I can create a ObjectAnimator for color change -

```
 ValueAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(vector, "fillColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.light_green), getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        animator.setDuration(3000);
```

Comment: any other options for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [PathAnimatorInflater](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=vector-compat-master/library/src/main/java/com/wnafee/vector/compat/PathAnimatorInflater.java) class and rewriting the setupAnimatorForPath to accept Strings instead TypedArray it is possible. Here is a method that uses this -

```
private ObjectAnimator getAnimator(AnimatedVectorDrawable vector, int in, int out, int delay) {
    ObjectAnimator animator = new ObjectAnimator();
    animator.setTarget(vector);
    animator.setPropertyName("pathData");
    TypeEvaluator evaluator = PathAnimatorInflater.setupAnimatorForPath(animator, getResources().getString(in), getResources().getString(out));
    if (evaluator == null) {
        return null;
    }
    animator.setEvaluator(evaluator);
    animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
    animator.setDuration(3000);
    animator.setStartDelay(delay);
    return animator;
}
```

But to use this with AnimatedVectorDrawable it needs some changes in Vector classes also.