# How to create animation with provided PathData using ObjectAnimator progrmattically in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android

I have tried to create animation using **ObjectAnimator** with **PathData** as property name

The xml code I have used:

```
<objectAnimator
android:duration="166"
android:propertyName="pathData"
android:valueFrom="M -7,-7 l 14,0 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 l 0,14 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 l -14,0 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 l 0,-14 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z M 7,-9 c 0,0 -14,0 -14,0 c -1.1044921875,0 -2,0.8955078125 -2,2 c 0,0 0,14 0,14 c 0,1.1044921875 0.8955078125,2 2,2 c 0,0 14,0 14,0 c 1.1044921875,0 2,-0.8955078125 2,-2 c 0,0 0,-14 0,-14 c 0,-1.1044921875 -0.8955078125,-2 -2,-2 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z"
android:valueTo="M 0,-0.05 l 0,0 c 0.02761423749,0 0.05,0.02238576251 0.05,0.05 l 0,0 c 0,0.02761423749 -0.02238576251,0.05 -0.05,0.05 l 0,0 c -0.02761423749,0 -0.05,-0.02238576251 -0.05,-0.05 l 0,0 c 0,-0.02761423749 0.02238576251,-0.05 0.05,-0.05 Z M 7,-9 c 0,0 -14,0 -14,0 c -1.1044921875,0 -2,0.8955078125 -2,2 c 0,0 0,14 0,14 c 0,1.1044921875 0.8955078125,2 2,2 c 0,0 14,0 14,0 c 1.1044921875,0 2,-0.8955078125 2,-2 c 0,0 0,-14 0,-14 c 0,-1.1044921875 -0.8955078125,-2 -2,-2 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z"
android:valueType="pathType"/>
```

How to create animation with provided PathData using ObjectAnimator progrmattically in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Hello your question is not making sense can you be clear about what you wanna do exactly, animation okay but what kind of animation?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36161057/how-to-create-objectanimator-with-valuetype-pathtype-programmatically), you need to rewrite the [`setupAnimatorForPath`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/7b9c912/core/java/android/animation/AnimatorInflater.java#476) to accept Strings instead TypedArray. To do this you need to install the [`VectorCompat`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VectorCompat) nuget package. You could install it by using:

```
Install-Package VectorCompat -Version 1.0.5
```

And in xamarin you also need to create the `PathDataEvaluator`.

For example, the `PathDataEvaluator`:

```
public class PathDataEvaluator : Java.Lang.Object, ITypeEvaluator
{
    private PathParser.PathDataNode[] mNodeArray;
    private PathDataEvaluator() { }

    public PathDataEvaluator(PathParser.PathDataNode[] nodeArray)
    {
        mNodeArray = nodeArray;
    }

    public Java.Lang.Object Evaluate(float fraction, Java.Lang.Object startValue, Java.Lang.Object endValue)
    {
        PathParser.PathDataNode[] startPathData =startValue.ToArray<PathParser.PathDataNode>();
        PathParser.PathDataNode[] endPathData = endValue.ToArray<PathParser.PathDataNode>();

        if (!PathParser.CanMorph(startPathData, endPathData))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't interpolate between"
                    + " two incompatible pathData");
        }
        if (mNodeArray == null || !PathParser.CanMorph(mNodeArray, startPathData))
        {
            mNodeArray = PathParser.DeepCopyNodes(startPathData);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < startPathData.Length; i++)
        {
            mNodeArray[i].InterpolatePathDataNode(startPathData[i],
                    endPathData[i], fraction);
        }
        return mNodeArray;
    }
}
```

And the code for `objectAnimator`:

```
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = new ObjectAnimator();
        objectAnimator.SetTarget(TARGET);
        objectAnimator.PropertyName = "pathData";
        PathDataEvaluator evaluator = null;
        string fromString = "M -7,-7 l 14,0 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 l 0,14 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 l -14,0 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 l 0,-14 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z M 7,-9 c 0,0 -14,0 -14,0 c -1.1044921875,0 -2,0.8955078125 -2,2 c 0,0 0,14 0,14 c 0,1.1044921875 0.8955078125,2 2,2 c 0,0 14,0 14,0 c 1.1044921875,0 2,-0.8955078125 2,-2 c 0,0 0,-14 0,-14 c 0,-1.1044921875 -0.8955078125,-2 -2,-2 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z";
        string toString = "M 0,-0.05 l 0,0 c 0.02761423749,0 0.05,0.02238576251 0.05,0.05 l 0,0 c 0,0.02761423749 -0.02238576251,0.05 -0.05,0.05 l 0,0 c -0.02761423749,0 -0.05,-0.02238576251 -0.05,-0.05 l 0,0 c 0,-0.02761423749 0.02238576251,-0.05 0.05,-0.05 Z M 7,-9 c 0,0 -14,0 -14,0 c -1.1044921875,0 -2,0.8955078125 -2,2 c 0,0 0,14 0,14 c 0,1.1044921875 0.8955078125,2 2,2 c 0,0 14,0 14,0 c 1.1044921875,0 2,-0.8955078125 2,-2 c 0,0 0,-14 0,-14 c 0,-1.1044921875 -0.8955078125,-2 -2,-2 c 0,0 0,0 0,0 Z";
        PathParser.PathDataNode[] nodesFrom = PathParser.CreateNodesFromPathData(fromString);
        PathParser.PathDataNode[] nodesTo = PathParser.CreateNodesFromPathData(toString);
        if (nodesFrom != null)
        {
            if (nodesTo != null)
            {
                objectAnimator.SetObjectValues(nodesFrom, nodesTo);

                if (!PathParser.CanMorph(nodesFrom, nodesTo))
                {
                    throw new InflateException(" Can't morph from " + fromString + " to " + toString);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                objectAnimator.SetObjectValues((Object)nodesFrom);
            }
            evaluator = new PathDataEvaluator(PathParser.DeepCopyNodes(nodesFrom));
        }
        else if (nodesTo != null)
        {
            objectAnimator.SetObjectValues((Object)nodesTo);
            evaluator = new PathDataEvaluator(PathParser.DeepCopyNodes(nodesTo));
        }

        objectAnimator.SetEvaluator(evaluator);
        objectAnimator.SetDuration(166);
        objectAnimator.Start();
```

You could refer to this [Link](https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat) for some more information.

Comment: I have faced this error... obj\Debug\lp\3\jl\res\values-v21\values.xml:1: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Button'.

Comment: Have you installed `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` package?

Comment: Yes still i face same issue

Comment: @yoganathank What's your target api level and minimum api level?

Comment: Android 5.1 API22

Comment: @yoganathank That's odd. I tried API 22, the issue is gone after I install the `Appcompat` package. Have you tried clean and rebuild?